# checking path capitalization of pwd

Tags: command-line, path

Is there a quick way to check in terminal that the terminal command `pwd` returns the correct capitalization of the path?

Note that if you do `cd ~/desktop` then `pwd` would tell you that your path is `/Users/foo/desktop` rather than the correct `/Users/foo/Desktop`.

EDIT: Motivation: build systems need a way to check this early on, otherwise it's really [hard to debug](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sage-support/yIKbb3fW35M/jULeMShOCgAJ). An unsuspecting user uses a wrong capitalisation, starts a build, gets errors that are very puzzling.

EDIT2: Silently accepting incorrectly capitalised input for `cd` is the *standard* behaviour of `bash` on an HFS+ file system, and thus for the vast majority of OSX users. Then, `pwd` is a `bash` builtin, and it simply takes the content of the path stack of the shell (typos included).

Comment: Why would you not want to do `cd ~/Desktop` then `pwd` would tell you `/Users/user/Desktop/`

Comment: this is to make a build system more robust. I'll edit the question with more details

Comment: 1)  How can `pwd` return anything but the correct capitalization of the current directory?  2)  How can you `cd ~/desktop` and go to `/Users/foo/Desktop` unless you have a symlink or something?  This question makes no sense.

Comment: tl;dr If your software require case sensitivity then your only option would be to build inside a HFSX disk image.

Comment: @Allan : try what I say in the question, on a case-insensitive filesystem! You will be surprised. No, you do not need symlinks or anything. It just works (TM :-)) - and shoots you in the foot along the way.

Comment: @fd0 the software itself does not require case sensitivity. But if a person doing a command-line build makes a typo in a path, then --- boom!

Comment: I don't think I have used a case insensitive f/s for over 15 years now.  Who uses case insensitive file systems?

Comment: @Allan I suppose 95% of Apple users do. By default Apple ships machines with HFS+ filesystems (i.e. case insensitive).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `/bin/pwd`

```
cd ~/desktop
/bin/pwd -P
```